# How to get Angularjs Hidden field value without any button action?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want get the angularjs hidden field value without any button action. I'm new in angularjs if any link available for this solution please send to me

Code given below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="id" ng-init="id=12"></input>
</div>
<script>
function TestController($scope) {

        alert($scope.id);
}
</script>
```

Comment: what did not work?

Comment: i'm getting undefined value. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is, in controller alert is invoked before ng-init get set,

try this,

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope,$timeout) {
   $timeout(function() {
         alert($scope.id);
    })
});
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/k89LhOIt3bCWFXvRyxhB?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is that the `alert(...)` call is executed before the `id` variable is initialized.

This seems to work

```js
function TestController($scope, $timeout) {
        $timeout(function(){alert($scope.id);},0, true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="id" ng-init="id=12">     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create init function and observe via `$watch`

```js
function TestController($scope) {
  this.init = function() {
    $scope.id = 12;

    $scope.$watch('id', function(value, oldValue) {
      console.log('changed', $scope.id)
    });
    console.log('id has been initialized');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="vm.init()" ng-controller="TestController as vm">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="id">
  <input type="text" placeholder="just test input" name="other" ng-model="id">
</div>
```